# Pass Information from Webform Note to Form

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I'm creating a webform and I would like to create a bunch of checkboxes between two dates:
[image]

Now I could just use the checkboxes element, but this is going change every year. I would like to generate it from a value on the webform node page.

This would most conveniently be a date range field, but I'm thinking of using jQuery/JS to take the values of the date range field and format it as a value in the default values. However, I don't know how to get the default values and make them output the checkboxes.
[image]

I also saw the "days" predefined element in the checkboxes, but unfortunately, that only displays Sunday, Monday, Tuesday....Saturday.

How would I program this?